# How to use regex to pull out a specific value in classic asp

Tags: regex, asp-classic

I can't figure out a way to pull out two numbers in a string and save them in a different variable in classic asp.

The string is:

```
 "\1800_411.pdf.log"
```

All I was trying to do is to save the first number which is 1800 in a variable and save the 411 in a different variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about:

```
(\d+)_(\d+)
```

This would save them into two capturing groups. See here: https://regex101.com/r/v83Zbt/1

Comment: Thank you for your answer, This is perfect except, I am not sure how to use classic asp to save these numbers in variables

Comment: @SachJot very sorry but I don't know asp!